# Is it possible to implement value-indexed data types on OCaml/ReasonML?

Tags: types, ocaml, agda

I've recently been introduced to agda and this caught my attention:

```
data Vector (A : Set) : Nat → Set where
  []  : Vector A zero
  _∷_ : {n : Nat} → A → Vector A n → Vector A (suc n)

_++_ : ∀ {a m n} {A : Set a} → Vec A m → Vec A n → Vec A (m + n)
[]       ++ ys = ys
(x ∷ xs) ++ ys = x ∷ (xs ++ ys)
```

I tried to implement this kind of array in OCaml but I realised I cannot index types over values. I managed to use types for length but I can't enforce the concatenation check `Vec A m → Vec A n → Vec A (m + n)`.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml does not support dependent types, so it is not possible to have value indexed types. However, for length-indexed lists, it is possible to get pretty far with just GADTs.

The starting point is to define a type construction to represent the `succ` operator

```
type 'a succ = private Succ
```

Then a nice and classical definition of Peano natural number is

```
type ('x,'x_plus_n) nat =
  | Zero: ('n, 'n) nat (* n + 0 = n *)
  | Succ: ('x,'x_plus_n) nat -> ('x, 'x_plus_n succ) nat
  (* succ ( n + x ) = n + succ x *)
let zero = Zero
let one = Succ zero
```

The advantage of this representation is that addition can be defined by stating that adding `x + y` to `n` can be decomposed into `(n + x) + y`:

```
let rec (+): type n n_plus_x n_plus_x_plus_y.
(n,n_plus_x) nat -> (n_plus_x, n_plus_x_plus_y) nat -> (n,n_plus_x_plus_y) nat =
fun x y -> match y with
| Zero -> x
| Succ y -> Succ( x + y )

let two = one + one
```

From them defining length-indexed list is just a matter of storing this natural integer encoding inside the type of the list:

```
type ('elt,'x,'x_plus_length)  nlist =
  | []: ('elt, 'n,'n) nlist
  | (::) : 'elt * ('elt, 'n, 'n_plus_length) nlist
     -> ('elt, 'n,'n_plus_length succ) nlist
```

We are using here the fact that `::` is an infix type constructor and that 
`[1;2;3]` is just some syntactic sugar for `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: []`
which means that we can write

```
let l = [1;2;3]
let l' = [1;2]
```

and that `l=l'` fails with a type error.

Wit this definition, getting back a typed length can be done with just

```
let rec len: type inf sup. ('elt, inf,sup) nlist -> (inf,sup) nat =
  function
  | [] -> Zero
  | _ :: q -> Succ (len q)
```

and concatening two lists require just a bit of finesse to determine the order of the type arguments:

```
let rec (@): type inf mid sup.
  ('elt,mid,sup) nlist -> ('elt,inf,mid) nlist -> ('elt, inf,sup) nlist =
fun left right -> match left with
  | [] -> right
  | a :: q -> a :: (q @ right)
```

In fact the major obstacle to using those kind of lists is the value restriction that makes it painful to keep all the type variables involved generic (and not weakly polymorphic).

Comment: Is there a way to prevent value restriction for the result of the addition?

Comment: You can wrap up everything in thunk `let two () = one + one`, but that's all.